# Is it possible to tie sql server paging to the report viewer

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Can we improve the performance of the report viewer.  Instead of bringing the whole dataset, can we bring only the page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use the limit clause.

Comment: You mean TOP - `LIMIT` is MySQL/Postgres syntax.

Comment: Sorry about that - the sql-server tag was added after I posted.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, controls can be AJAX based, but the reports themselves bring the whole data in and render it. I have not seen reports that bring data back page by page as implemented on many web sites.

Now if you just want to show a subset of data, you can do something like this

```
SELECT TOP 100 ColumnList
FROM Tables
```